# Immutable Nokogiri documents

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

Once I parse a complex HTML document into a Nokogiri::HTML object, I want to pass it around to various classes to extract information from it. Recently I discovered some code that accidentally mutated the original object:

```
body = Nokogiri::HTML(html_text_from_the_internets)
tables = body.css('table')
tables.each do {|table|
  table.css('br').each do |line_break|
    line_break.replace("\n")
  end
end
```

All `<br>` tags are now removed from all tables in `body`

Is there are a way to freeze `body` so it can not be mutated? That way, during testing, hopefully, I can catch other side-effect mutations before they break things. Calling `body.freeze` doesn't work (probably because it only freezes the top-level object).

Comment: You could .dup it and compare wether it changed after your code runs i guess.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can "deep freeze" a nested object.

A deep freeze is essentially a traversal that freezes all sub-objects.

You can write it yourself if you want, or use a gem such as [**ice_nine**](https://github.com/dkubb/ice_nine)

Another way to test, that doesn't involve freezing, is to compare the overall object before and after. An easy way to do this is Marshall dump the object before, and after, and compare them. If the dumps are different, they will show you exactly what has changed. (Similarly, you could do a deep clone a.k.a. deep dup before, and use that for the comparison. Similarly, you could use an object hash.)